# Remove columns with a date and time stamp Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The CSV I am working has a column that is named "First Detected" and has data that looks like this "2/13/2016 23:04". I am trying to use pandas to delete the columns that do not match a date I enter, I also want it to not care about what the time stamp is. For instance I want to keep the rows with the date 4/12/2016 and delete the rest. How can this be done with Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
date = '4/12/2016'
df = pd.DataFrame({'First Detected':['2/13/2016 23:04','2/13/2016 23:04','4/12/2016 23:04']})
print (df)

    First Detected
0  2/13/2016 23:04
1  2/13/2016 23:04
2  4/12/2016 23:04

df['First Detected'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First Detected'])

df = df[df['First Detected'].dt.date == pd.to_datetime(date).date()]
print (df)
       First Detected
2 2016-04-12 23:04:00
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was wanting. Thanks.